# Re-installation of AppArmor misses some files

Tags: apparmor

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and lately I reinstalled AppArmor:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apparmor*
sudo apt-get install apparmor --reinstall
sudo service apparmor restart
```

When I am trying to parse a profile with `apparmor_praser` I got error:

> AppArmor parser error for my.profile in my.profile at line 1:
>   Could not open 'tunables/global'

I checked my ApprAmor folder and noticed it missing some files:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apparmor.d# ls ./tunables/
home.d  multiarch.d  xdg-user-dirs.d
```

While, before I removed the files I had these files:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/
alias  apparmorfs  dovecot  global  home  home.d  kernelvars  multiarch  multiarch.d  proc  securityfs  sys  xdg-user-dirs  xdg-user-dirs.d
```

It seems that the installation didn't install all the dependencies libraries.
I tried also these ones:

```
apt-get install apparmor-utils apparmor-easyprof apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu
```

But I still don't have important files such as `tunables/global`.

Any idea how I can reinstall AppArmor as it came up with Ubuntu default installation ?

Comment: please don't `rm -rf` random files in /etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to this place:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/apparmor

download:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/apparmor/2.10.95-0ubuntu2.10/apparmor_2.10.95.orig.tar.gz

Inside this `tar` file I wend to `../profiles/apparmor.d` and extracted all the content to `/etc/apparmor.d` by:

```
cp -r ./apparmor.d/ /etc/apparmor.d/
```

But it weird that I needed to do it manually.
I will be glad if someone can share automatic way to do it with `apt-get`.

Comment: i had the same problem.  i wish apparmor would just disappear.  it's perhaps the most useless package for desktop that inserts itself everywhere and is impossible to remove